# Have any Republican senators announced they'll oppose the motion to proceed on 2017-07-26?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate, healthcare, republican-party

[This Axios article](https://www.axios.com/the-senates-evolving-health-care-plan-2464948865.html) describes what the Senate is planning to do tomorrow on Healthcare.  First they'll vote on a motion to proceed on the House Republican Healthcare bill, the AHCA.  Assuming it passes, they'll vote on the Senate Republican Healthcare bill, the BCRA.  If the BCRA fails, which it probably will, they will then vote on a straight repeal of Obamacare.  If that too fails, which it probably will, then they'll start debating various amendments to the House bill (the AHCA) and see where they can go from there.

But all of this is contingent on successfully voting on the motion to proceed.  So my question is, have any Republican senators publicly announced their intentions to vote no on the motion to proceed tomorrow?  Because it just takes three Republican senators to vote no and the motion to proceed will fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, Senator Susan Collins of Maine has publicly confirmed that she [will vote 'no'](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/24/us/politics/senate-health-bill-obamacare-repeal-and-replace-trump-mcconnell.html) on the procedural vote.

---

According to the same NYT article, the following Senators could also vote 'no' on the procedural vote.

**(Senators who are *likely to* vote 'no')**

- Shelley Moore Capito of West Virginia
- Lisa Murkowski of Alaska
- Rand Paul of Kentucky

---

In addition, [CNN listed](http://edition.cnn.com/2017/07/25/politics/senate-poised-to-vote-today-on-health-care/index.html) these Senators who have expressed their concerns towards the bill. It's unclear at the moment if they are convinced by the Republican leadership to vote for the motion to proceed, so they might too vote 'No'.

**(Senators who *might* vote 'no')**

- Rob Portman of Ohio
- Dean Heller of Nevada
- Mike Lee of Utah
- Jerry Moran of Kansas
- Ron Johnson of Wisconsin

---

Republicans can only lose 2 votes for the motion to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

We are now past the [vote](http://www.npr.org/2017/07/25/539270923/senators-to-vote-on-whether-to-proceed-with-health-care-debate).  Only Susan Collins and Lisa Murkowski (and forty-eight Democrats and independents) voted against the motion to proceed.  Vice President Mike Pence cast the tiebreaking vote.

The next two [votes failed](http://www.cnn.com/2017/07/25/politics/senate-health-care-vote/index.html).  The first was the repeal-and-replace vote (the Better Care Reconciliation Act).  The next was the clean repeal vote.  They did not vote on the American Health Care Act.  They could vote on it later.  The next step is to debate the next steps for at least forty-eight hours.

The one thing that we know that they are considering is a series of votes on individual aspects of the original Patient Protection & Affordable Care Act (colloquially known as Obamacare).  This includes unpopular parts of the bill, like the individual mandate.  They have been calling this skinny repeal.  They may consider other things after debate.