# Has the text of McConnell's "skinny repeal" bill been released?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate, healthcare, affordable-care-act

[This Business Insider article](http://www.businessinsider.com/senate-republican-health-care-bill-motion-to-proceed-vote-count-2017-7) details Senate Republicans' plans regarding Healthcare today.  First, the Senate will take up a motion to proceed.  Then assuming that passes (which is in doubt as I discuss [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/23093/1953)), there will be votes on the following bills:

1. The ORRA, a repeal of as much of Obamacare as can be passed through reconciliation, pretty much the same bill that the House and Senate passed in 2015 knowing full well that Obama would veto it
2. The BCRA, the Senate Republican Healthcare bill, possibly with addition of an amendment authored by Ted Cruz and Rob Portman which would both allow insurance companies to sell plans that don't meet the minimum coverage requirements of Obamacare, and would add $100 billion to an insurance stabilization fund
3. The AHCA, the House Republican Healthcare bill, possibly with amendments added
4. A "skinny repeal" bill authored by Mitch McConnell, "a bundle of smaller amendments focused on repealing aspects of Obamacare like the individual mandate and medical-device tax"

The first three bills are expected to fail, and then Mitch McConnell hopes that the "skinny repeal" bill will pass.  So then the Senate would have passed something, and then House and Senate members could go into Conference to reconcile the differences between their bills.

Now the text of the first three bills are publicly available.  But my question is, has the text of McConnell's "skinny repeal" bill been released to the public yet?  Or is Mitch McConnell planning to only release it once the first three bills get voted down?  If it hasn't been released, have any Senators other than Mitch McConnel seen the text of this bill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Wednesday night, **no**, and it may not even exist yet.

To quote from [FiveThirtyEight's live blog's summary post](http://fivethirtyeight.com/live-blog/senate-vote-health-care/?lpup=23491658#livepress-update-23491658) (the 5:52 one, in case the direct link doesn't work) (emphasis mine):

> The Senate’s main two Obamacare bills — “repeal and replace” and “repeal and delay” — have both been rejected. **Republicans are working, behind closed doors, on some kind of limited repeal plan that they hope can pass (the so-called “skinny” repeal).** Senators have suggested that that plan would roll back the individual mandate, the employer mandate and the medical device tax. **But the contours of the “skinny” repeal are likely to change**, depending on what senators will support and what follows the rules of the reconciliation process.

---

#### Update:

As of Thursday night, [around 9:56 PM](http://fivethirtyeight.com/live-blog/senate-vote-health-care/?lpup=23135566#livepress-update-23135566), the text of the bill was released.  You can find it [here](https://www.budget.senate.gov/imo/media/doc/HealthCareFreedomAct.pdf).